# Find input values of submitted form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm sure this is fairly simple, but showing up my lack of knowledge. I am trying to submit a form and do something with it via Ajax. I am struggling to get the values of the information that's been input. The code below is what I have cobbled together, but it's not working.

```
jQuery('.notes-form').submit(function(){

    var _type = jQuery('input[name="type"]', this);
    var _candidate = jQuery('input[name="candidate"]', this);
    var _note = jQuery('input[name="note"]', this);

    console.log(_note);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in case it helps anyone else. The original error (removed from the question) was unrelated due to Cloudflare's development mode switching off between iterations. The result of the console.log for the above led to the correct code below. (Or at least code that works!)

```
jQuery('.notes-form').submit(function(event){

    var _type = jQuery('input[name="type"]', this).val();
    var _candidate = jQuery('input[name="candidate"]', this).val();
    var _note = jQuery('input[name="note"]', this).val();

    console.log(_note);
});
```